# Data manipulation in R: Column divided by the number of rows that contains the corresponding value

Tags: r, dplyr

```
A = c(10009, 10009,  10009, 10009,  10011, 10011, ...)
B = c(23908, 230908, 230908,230908, 23514, 23514, ...)
```

I have a dataframe with the above 2 columns. How do I create a third column, C, that is B divided by the number of rows that contains the corresponding value in column A?

I tried the below but the error is: "problem with mutate(), column C".

```
DF = DF %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(C = B/n(A))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant `length`:

```
DF %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(C = B / length(A))
```

Result on your example dataset:

```
      A      B     C
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 10009  23908  5977
2 10009 230908 57727
3 10009 230908 57727
4 10009 230908 57727
5 10011  23514 11757
6 10011  23514 11757
```

Comment: I faced this error:
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `count`. i `C = B/nrow(A)`. i `C` must be size 4 or 1, not 0.

Comment: @Grace Oops! Sorry edited mine!

Comment: @Grace Happy to help!! Feel free to mark whenever time is up :P

Answer (score 2):

`n()` doesn't accept any arguments. Try -

```
library(dplyr)

DF <- DF %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(C = B/n()) %>% ungroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: A longer version (maybe not the best) for your task might be first to use `add_count` and then mutate: With this longer version you can follow the steps:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  add_count() %>% 
  mutate(C = B/n) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-n)
```

output:

```
      A      B     C
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 10009  23908  5977
2 10009 230908 57727
3 10009 230908 57727
4 10009 230908 57727
5 10011  23514 11757
6 10011  23514 11757
```

First answer some seconds behind Ronak Shah!

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(C = B/n())
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, C := B/.N, A]
```